# Show: $W:=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:-1<x_i<1, i=1,2,3\right\}$ is a 3-dim. submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> > Use two different argumentations to show that
> >     $$
> > W:=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:-1<x_i<1, i=1,2,3\right\}
> > $$
> >      is a 3-dim. submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**1) Parametrization (map)**

To show that $W$ is a 3-dim. submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider the inclusion
$$
\varphi\colon W\to\mathbb{R}^3, x\longmapsto x.
$$
This is an immersion which maps $W$ to $W$ as a homeomorphism.

**2) Don't know a special name for this.**

Consider
$$
E_k:=\left\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_{k+1}=...=x_n=0\right\}
$$
with $k=n=3$ here. Furthermore consider
$$
\theta\colon W\to W, x\longmapsto x. 
$$
This is an invertible function which fullfills, because of $E_3=\mathbb{R}^3$,
$$
\theta(W\cap W)=\theta(W)=W=E_3\cap W=W.
$$

---

So in 1) and 2) I used two different characterizations of submanifolds which I found in my analysis book in order two explain the claim. Would be nice to hear if my both explanations are correct.

With kind regards

math12

Answer (score 0):

In 1), you should first mention the fact that an open subset of an m-manifold is an m-manifold with the induced atlas (otherwise it does not make sense to talk of immersions, if you do not know whether they are manifolds), and then since you know immersion + homeomorphism, this implies that $\varphi(W) \cong W$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (by a famous lemma).

In 2) I think that you are using the definition of regular submanifold, but it sounds a bit awkward to me. It probably depends on your definition.

Anyway, I would also try out a more complicated example: this is almost too easy (you only need one chart) and it all sounds a bit artificial. You could try with $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen that you've posted it two years ago...